# Invalid package manifest "package.xml"

Tags: ros, catkin, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I found a some entries but none seem to help with my problem. I am currently following the instructions to install turtlebot on this site:
http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Turtlebot%20Installation
when running following command under point 2.2:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y
```

I get following stack trace:

```
nicolas@myworkstation:~/rocon$ rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y

ERROR: Rosdep experienced an error: Invalid package manifest "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/package.xml": Error(s) in /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/package.xml:
- The manifest must not contain the following tags: depend, build_export_depend, buildtool_export_depend
Please go to the rosdep page [1] and file a bug report with the stack trace below.
[1] : http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep

rosdep version: 0.11.2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 136, in rosdep_main
    exit_code = _rosdep_main(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 345, in _rosdep_main
    return _package_args_handler(command, parser, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 416, in _package_args_handler
    pkgs = find_catkin_packages_in(path, options.verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/catkin_packages.py", line 33, in find_catkin_packages_in
    packages = find_packages(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py", line 87, in find_packages
    package = parse_package(os.path.join(basepath, path))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 315, in parse_package
    return parse_package_string(f.read(), filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 448, in parse_package_string
    raise InvalidPackage('Error(s) in %s:%s' % (filename, ''.join(['\n- %s' % e for e in errors])))
InvalidPackage: Invalid package manifest "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/package.xml": Error(s) in /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/package.xml:
- The manifest must not contain the following tags: depend, build_export_depend, buildtool_export_depend
```

There must be a problem with my package.xml file.

It seems that the package version 2 might cause the error but I honestly don't know how to fix it. Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213569/invalid-package-manifest-%22package.xml%22/) by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-07-13**:
Can you post the package.xml that causes the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your rospkg version is likely outdated. Please see http://answers.ros.org/question/207802/rospkgmanifestinvalidmanifest/

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1